# Is there a way to change the style formatting of an element within a class?

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-specificity

I created a class:

how to I format a `p` tag within this class with a different font size?

I tried an inline method but I am guessing I can do this globally

```
.cities {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color:lightyellow;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: please post the relevant HTML section

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `p` tag inside a tag contains the class `cities`
you can do:

```
.cities p{
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color:lightyellow;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another class to the relevant HTML tag and combine the two classes in a CSS rule just for the font-size:

```
.cities.smaller {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

The relevant `p` tag would like like this in HTML:

```
<p class="cities smaller">...</p>
```

The combination of two classes will "overrule" the single class due to a higher CSS *specifity*. Here an example in a snippet:

```css
.cities {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color:lightyellow;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}
.cities.smaller {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<p class="cities">This is an element that has only the "cities" class applied to it</p>
<p class="cities smaller"> This will have a smaller font-size, but otherwise look the same as elements which have the "cities" class</p>
```

Also note that in this example the `.smaller` class will only be effective in combination with the `.cities` class, since in CSS it only appears in a combined selector. If you want to use it also in combination with other classes (or alone),  you can create a single-selector class like `.smaller { font-size: 12px; }` instead.

Comment: In your example has <p class="cities smaller" inherited all the other attributes (font-family, background-color etc. ) from class="cities" ? I am new to CSS. I have not read as much yet. Thanks

Comment: yes. all the other parameters are defined by the `.cities` rule, and `.cities.smaller` adds and overwrites the font-size.

Comment: Thanks. Is it wrong to presume you can add code that allows one to define a different font-size for the h2 tag through cities.smaller for example.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean - in your question you wrote about a `p` tag  (?). If you want to assign all these settings to an `h2` tag, you can write `<h2 class="cities smaller">....</h2>`  in the HTML code and use the CSS above. But you would also have to add `font-weight: normal` to one of those CSS rules, since an h2 by default is set in a *bold* font-weight, which you would need to overwrite.

Comment: @MatthewB: I'd recommend editing your question to include your markup as Brian suggested earlier. I noticed your question starts with "I created a class:" but there's an odd break after that. You probably forgot your markup there.